# Помощь с Задачей на Java. Нужно найти ошибку

Tags: java

## **Суть задачи такова:**

**На входе**, в первой строке задано натуральное число N – количество жильцов (N ≤ 100). В последующих N строках располагается информация о всех жильцах: каждая строка содержит два целых числа: V и S – возраст и пол человека (1 ≤ V ≤ 100, S – 0 или 1). Мужскому полу соответствует значение S=1, а женскому – S=0

**На выходе**, должно содержатся номер самого старшего мужчины в списке. Если таких жильцов несколько, то следует вывести наименьший номер. Если жильцов мужского пола нет, то выведите -1.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int number = in.nextInt();

int[] citizen = new int[number]; // 25 70 100 3
int[] gender = new int[number]; // 1 1 0 1
int max = 0, Index = 0, male = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < citizen.length; i++) {
    citizen[i] = in.nextInt();
    gender[i] = in.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i < citizen.length; i++) {
    if(citizen[i] > max && gender[i] == 1){
        max = citizen[i];
        Index = i+1; // Нахождение индекса самого старого мужчины
    }
    if (gender[i] == 0){ // Проверка на наличие мужчин
        male = 0;
    }
    else male++;
}

if (male == 0) System.out.println("-1");
else  System.out.println(Index);
```

В компиляторе всё работает как надо, но бот для тестирования не принимает код, не проходит 4 тест, номера и какие тесты проходят не известно, вожусь с задачей очень долго не понимаю что тут не так? Прошу помощи.

Ведь это связано с вариантами значений, я не могу понять какие значения он использует что программа не выдает правильный ответ.

Comment: Это Stepik? Если да, то уточните у авторов курса или поищите в комментариях, что значит ошибка теста №4

Comment: 2 0 1 1 0 на выходе должны получить:
1 Такое тоже не проходит: 10 0 1 10 0 17 1 188 1 114 1 12 0 13 1 18 0 20 1 1 0

Comment: Нет это не Stepik, а ACMP

Comment: Видимо не учел в коде возраст 0, щас попробую решить

Comment: Тут дело не в нуле, по условию возраст 0 не должен быть, но так же код не принимает - 1 1 и 1 0. Щас пытаюсь понять

Comment: if (gender[i] == 0){ // Проверка на наличие мужчин
        male = 0;
    } - вот тут, если последний элемент женского пола, получаете что мужчин вообще нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем так сложно? Зачем Вам эти массивы? На лету считайте

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int number = in.nextInt();

int index = -1;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  int age = in.nextInt();
  int gender = in.nextInt();
  if (gender == 1 && age > max) {
    index = i + 1;
    max = age;
  }
}
System.out.println(Index);
```

А конкретно в Вашем коде, ошибка здесь

```
if (gender[i] == 0){ // Проверка на наличие мужчин
    male = 0;
}
else male++;
```

Что будет, если последней будет идти женщина?

Если уже делать проверку (хотя я показал, что она не нужна), то она должна быть такой

```
if (gender[i] == 1){ // Проверка на наличие мужчин
    male++;
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен.

Я не учел то что если последним будет женщина что я обнуляю число мужчин, спасибо за поправку, я использовал массивы для практики, но щас увидел что можно и без них спасибо большое, ваш код изменен только на одну строчку, не обновлялся максимальный возраст. Но в целом ответ на мой вопрос был отвечен.

Только вот для чего для индекса -1? просто по настроению? Да и по условию возраст не может быть ниже 1, или тут какая то хитрость? хм ...

Comment: @TheOldManPickAssO Если не встретился ни один мужчина, то индекс уже -1 и никаких дополнительных проверок не нужно. Обновление максимального возраста сейчас поправлю. А возраст -1 - это для верности. В идеале там вообще должно быть `Integer.MIN`